# How to make, an image that is pulled in by category, link to a parent posts page not to its category page it is located in. Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, content-management-system, permalinks

I'm new to php (' still struggle with syntax :-) ') and wordpress and I'm building a web-site where I am looping to my category page all the images tagged with that category. I need the images to be automatically linked to its parent post which should be a Clients page essentially. The code i'm using right now links me to the same category page instead of client page.

This is the code i'm using now to pull the images.

```
<?php 
    $query_images_args = array(
        'cat' => 3,
        'post_type'      => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => 'image,video',//img & video files include
        'post_status'    => 'inherit',
        'orderby'        => 'ACS',
        'posts_per_page' =>  30,
    );

    $query_images = new WP_Query( $query_images_args );

    if($query_images->have_posts()) : 
        while($query_images->have_posts()) : 
            $query_images->the_post();
?>


<a href="<?php get_permalink( $parent_id ); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">

        <?php echo $images = wp_get_attachment_image( $query_images->posts->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>

</a>  

        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php else : ?>
        <p>No media file yet</p>
    <?php endif;

    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

I hoped that this part `<a href="<?php get_permalink( $parent_id ); ?>` will link me to the clients page but it still links me to category page.

I think that the I have something wrong with hierarchy or the way do the linking part.

I have also checked this resource but it does not seem to do anything :
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/188736/get-the-title-and-url-of-the-attachment-parent-post

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are using a variable $parent_id that isn't set.

Try replacing:

```
<a href="<?php get_permalink( $parent_id ); ?>"
```

with:

```
<a href="<?php get_permalink( $post->post_parent ); ?>"
```